# Word for "coin-enamouredness"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

For a project of mine, I am looking for an English word for "the addiction of a person to coins". Right now I am thinking of *coin-enamouredness*. It will be used as an indicator in the following manner:

> - With [coin-enamouredness] of value 1, the person is inclined to trade his cash with coins, even if there is no profit after paying the sales tax.
> - With [coin-enamouredness] of 5, the person is inclined to trade his cash with coins, even if he has to pay tax from his own money.
> - With [coin-enamouredness] of −5, the person does the opposite, willing to trade his coin to money even if he has to cover the tax himself.

Is there a better word?

Comment: *Numismatophilia* fits (*numisma-* from Greek νόμισμα *coin*). It can also be conveniently represented by the symbol ***N*** and a number.

Comment: This site is not meant for coining neologisms. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @AndrewLeach ***N*** and a number, eh? Like these? *numismatophilia* => **n13a**,
*localization* => **l10n**,
*internationalization* => **i18n**,
*unicodification* => **u13n**.
:)

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that's a very good answer, but, technically, why you do a commment instead of an answer?

Comment: Thanks tchrist, although it is a joke, it is a very good idea too, n13a fits better in some occassions in my project, like software code implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your notion of "enamouredness" becomes so extreme as to be dysfunctional, the psychological dependence might be called a mania (such as dipsomania).

If you were seeking a germanic-sounding term, you might use **münzenmania**. A spanish-flavoured variant could be **monedamania**. But you could give your neologism a sturdy Saxon root with **scillingmania** or **shillingmania**.

Comment: +1 for "sturdy Saxon root."  Who says neologisms always have to be Latinate?

Comment: Why monedamania and not manía-metálica? My dictionary has:

 metálico
n. specie, coin money (as opposed to paper currency)

Answer (score 0):

In finance, in a roughly analogous situation, investors can be characterised as risk-seeking (or risk-hungry) and risk-averse. So maybe coin-seeking/averse?

Comment: Good idea indeed, but it is a boolean value: risk-seeking/risk-averse. Need to change it to a scaler:)